# input focus does not fire/emit the first time

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3

I am using ionic 3, I have an input when it has focus it supposed to trigger a function which is a modal... but it doesn't emit unless I leave input focus and click again on the input for the modal to open

.html

```
  <ion-item inset>
    <ion-label class="labels" floating>Functional Area</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" formControlName="functionalArea" readonly (focus)="selectFunctionalArea()"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
```

.ts

```
  selectFunctionalArea(){
    let modal = this.modalCtrl.create('ModalSearch', {data: this.functionalAreaPack});
    modal.present();
  }
```

the first time I click on the input...it has focus but no modal, I have to leave the input, and click on it the second time and then I notice that 2 modals are opening. What am I doing wrong!

Comment: i had the same, try (click)=

Comment: @rashidnk the same thing happens with `click` `onChange` `ionInput` 
it seems that first click opens the keyboard

Comment: Better check this https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/6169

Comment: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/click-in-list-item-in-simulator-sometimes-doesnt-work-in-button-or-browser-it-does/54990

Comment: @rashidnk does this behavior only happen on browser ?? Also changing to button wont help me... cuz I want the selected item to be shown when returning back from that modal

Comment: @rashidnk I change `ion-item` to `button` but it only works the first time.. after refreshing page it doesn't work anymore... I have to serve again... this doesn't seem an optimal solution